# Azure read Excel Online document in Azure Function

Tags: excel, azure, azure-functions

I want to create an [Azure Function that connects to Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-twitter-email) that will be used as an [Add-in for Excel Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-excel). I want this Azure Function to read the Excel online file as a blob.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your description, I assume you want to use Logic App read the excel file then use Function to store the excel file into the Blob.

You could just do it with Logic App. Firstly use SharePoint connector to get the excel file content, then use Azure Blob connector, `Create blob` use file name and file content.

[image]

[image]

And here is the excel blob file in Azure Blob.

[image]